# How to get database name, password from web.config and use in another page

Tags: vb.net, web-config

I have to hard-coded DB details(User ID,Data Source,password)in my code(vb.net) as i am using SQL loader concept to load the data into a temporary table. Now i want to avoid the hard-code part.

Below is the code.

```
processStartInfo.Arguments = "User ID@Data Source/password " & FilePath & ctlFileName "
```

Now i want to provide the DB details(User ID,Data Source,password) from web.config to the above line.

How can i achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Always store your connection data in the web.config inside the appropriate section (where [you can also encrypt it](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647398.aspx))

For example

```
<connectionStrings>
     <add name="theConString" 
     connectionString="server=yourserver;database=yourdb;uid=username;password=pass;" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Then you can retrieve this data using the

```
Dim cnstr = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("theConString").ConnectionString
```

And finally you could pass the retrieved string to a SqlConnectionStringBuilder to get back the individual keys of the string

```
Dim builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(cnstr)
Dim password = builder.Password
....etc...
```

(I don't know which database are you using, this example is for Sql Server, but other providers have the same class used to parse or build a connectionstring)

According to your comment below, you have stored the connectionstring information in the AppSetting section. This is not the place recommended, however you can retrieve it from the AppSettings as well with

```
Dim cnStr = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings("youKeyName").ToString()
```

Comment: I have defined db values under </appSettings> not <connectionStrings> and also am using PL/SQL database. How to retrieve  password,uid etc from appsettings?

Comment: Why? The appropriate place for a connectionstring is in the ConnectionString section. For Oracle the process is the same, just use OracleConnectionStringBuilder

Comment: I could able to retrieve DB values with the SqlConnectionStringBuilder, currently am using Oracle db though. How it is possible?

Comment: SqlConnectionStringBuilder is a string parser. In the [connectionstring docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring(v=vs.110).aspx) many keys names are replaceable and if your Oracle connection string contains some of the allowed key dupes then the SqlConnectionStringBuilder can make sense of them